# Какое здесь правило?

Tags: правила

Не поняла, какое правило работает?
Рельеф Земли  — это сочетание разнообразных неровностей поверхности, **как больших, так и маленьких.**

Верно ли я понимаю, что перед "как" и "так" запятые стоят по той причине, что это согласованные обособленные определения, стоящие после главного слова - неровностей?

Answer (score 2):

> Рельеф Земли  — это сочетание разнообразных неровностей поверхности, **как больших, так и маленьких**.
>
> Не поняла, какое правило работает?

См. у Розенталя:

> **§ 14. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные двойными или парными союзами**
>
> 1. Если однородные члены предложения соединены двойными союзами ***если не…то, хотя…но*** или парными союзами (сопоставительными, градационными) ***как…так и, не так…как, не только…но и, не столько…сколько, насколько…настолько*** и т. п., то запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза…
>
> Постановка запятой перед первой частью парного союза связана с пояснительным характером всей конструкции: *Необходимо добиваться сокращения всех видов оружия, **как обычных, так и массового поражения*** (Газ.).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=96&ysclid=lr6m7mprqf413177841

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим **три варианта:**

(1) *Рельеф Земли  — это сочетание **как больших, так и маленьких** неровностей поверхности.*  Нет обособления в препозиции.

(2) *Рельеф Земли  — это сочетание неровностей поверхности, **как больших, так и маленьких.*** Обособление в постпозиции.

(3) *Рельеф Земли  — это сочетание **разнообразных** неровностей поверхности, **как больших, так и маленьких**.* Обособление в постпозиции + пояснение слова "разнообразных".

Таким образом, вы правы.Обособление оборота в заданном предложении определяется его позицией **после определяемого слова,** а пояснение — это дополнительный фактор.